# asp Server XML HTTP Object returns nothing

Tags: asp-classic

I am new to asp but need to fix a software for a friend. The problem is the routine that uses MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP to read an .asp page to produce a voucher. I have got it to work and display pages from any server, but when I try to open a page from my own Windows server the routine just returns blank, or hangs the server. Have tried everything. Wonder if it may be related to permissions?

It seems to get stuck in readyState=1.

```
<%
  Response.Buffer = True
  Dim objXMLHTTP, xml

  Set xml = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

  ' Opens the connection to the remote server.
  xml.Open "GET", "http://someurl/Testpage.asp", False

  ' Actually Sends the request and returns the data:
  xml.Send

  'Display the HTML both as HTML and as text
  Response.Write "<h1>The HTML text</h1><xmp>"
  Response.Write xml.responseText
  Response.Write "</xmp><p><hr><p><h1>The HTML Output</h1>"

  Response.Write xml.responseText


  Set xml = Nothing

%>
```

Comment: Hi, got it to display a .txt file, but not a simple .asp file. Permissions?

Comment: Also works with an .htm file, only .asp files dont work?

Comment: Please use the edit link below the question to add further details to the question, rather than using comments.  Also you might have to give further details of your .asp page.  Does it contain any JavaScript or other client side code?  Those would not execute when you fetch the page like that.

Comment: Try `Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")` - using the most recent version of MSXML sometimes makes a difference

Comment: What happens when you go to http://someurl/Testpage.asp directly?  Do you get valid XML back?

Comment: I don't think the ServerXMLHTTP object has an asp interpreter built into it, so it's unlikely to work with any but the most simple asp files. Could you maybe try it with an asp file that doesn't actually contain anything other than html?

Answer (score 0):

A development server has some restrictions on the amount of requests it can handle simultaneously.
Because you are in the process of executing one server-side script already, the server won't respond to the request you are sending via ServerXMLHTTP.

You can work around this by looking up the worker process for your development website in IIS Manager, and under advanced settings increase the maximum number of worker processes, which is propably set to 1.